# chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory

Tags: grub2, bash, mount, chroot

To fix grub, I tried following codes:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd6 /mnt 
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

While trying:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

it shows "**chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory**" error.

Please help me fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

The output for `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid | egrep -v ^loop&&sudo fdisk -l` is:

```
NAME   MOUNTPOINT LABEL                    SIZE FSTYPE   UUID
sda                                      931.5G          
├─sda1            ESP                      500M vfat     92E7-0D79
├─sda2                                     128M          
├─sda3                                   253.5G ntfs     B6B65DCCB65D8DAD
├─sda4            WINRETOOLS               450M ntfs     38F87730F876EB8E
├─sda5 [SWAP]                             15.3G swap     2a3bc8d1-c30e-4475-b23e-075969c6ec10
├─sda6                                   190.8G ext4     05298325-c1ee-4f08-8d7c-ea39d13a6958
└─sda7                                   428.8G ext4     2637ce7a-0e9b-407b-9b1e-021cf3bc536a
sdb    /cdrom     Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64   7.6G iso9660  2016-04-20-22-29-52-00
├─sdb1            Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64   1.4G iso9660  2016-04-20-22-29-52-00
└─sdb2            Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64   2.3M vfat     B1F5-0A13
sr0                                       1024M          
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.3 GiB, 1433468928 bytes, 2799744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 111A7812-C4EA-440D-AD62-0FE5922BA109

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1026048    1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     1288192  532901887 531613696 253.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1952602112 1953523711    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5   621402112  653402111  32000000  15.3G Linux swap
/dev/sda6   653402112 1053403135 400001024 190.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  1053403136 1952602111 899198976 428.8G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.




Disk /dev/sdb: 7.6 GiB, 8178892800 bytes, 15974400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0e0e8e70

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 2902111 2902112  1.4G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       2888004 2892739    4736  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Comment: Did you literally run `sudo mount /dev/sd6 /mnt`? That is unlikely to work. Furthermore, is it the correct / partition?

Comment: Will you edit your question and add the output of this command: `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid | egrep -v ^loop&&sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: @L.D.James I edited my question, please check it.

Comment: What architecture are the chroot and the Ubuntu you're running for setting up the chroot?

Comment: You appear to have two Linux partitions.  The largest is `/dev/sda7`.  There's a chance that your `/dev/sda6` might not be complete if it doesn't have a `/bin` folder.  Try the commands you already performed and test `/dev/sda7` as an alternative.  I thought the output would show a name of your partitions and one might say something like `Ubuntu OS` and a different one might say `DATA`.